# Update Trigger Can't Reference Deleted Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to reference the deleted table as well as the inserted table when the `AFTER UPDATE` trigger gets fired. The following works when trying to call the inserted table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER FLXUpdateTrigger ON WORK_ORDER
AFTER UPDATE
```

```
FROM 
            (WORK_ORDER 
            LEFT JOIN PART ON WORK_ORDER.PART_ID = PART.ID 
            LEFT JOIN PART_SITE ON WORK_ORDER.PART_ID = PART_SITE.PART_ID  
            JOIN Inserted AS i ON i.rowid = WORK_ORDER.rowid)
```

But then when I try and do the same exact thing for the delete table like so.

```
FROM        (WORK_ORDER 
            LEFT JOIN PART ON WORK_ORDER.PART_ID = PART.ID 
            LEFT JOIN PART_SITE ON WORK_ORDER.PART_ID = PART_SITE.PART_ID  
            JOIN deleted AS d ON d.rowid = WORK_ORDER.rowid)
```

It just displays the new data that was inserted for both tables. Am I joining these tables incorrectly? I am unable to just call `SELECT * FROM DELETED` because I do not need all of the columns from that tuple.

Comment: @BartHofland How can I reference all of my joined tables with the deleted data as well then?

Comment: What do you mean it "displays"? Triggers should not be presenting data to the presentation layer, and (in fact) doing so is deprecated.

Comment: @NickJuelich . . . I was wrong. It is an UPDATE trigger, so I would expect that the `INSERTED` and the `DELETED` virtual tables should contain the same amount of rows.

Comment: @Larnu I was just doing that for testing purposes so I could see what was wrong

Comment: @BartHofland, no, they won't, they will contain *similar* rows. The `inserted` virtual table will contain the new data, and `deleted` the old.

Comment: @Larnu . . . Yes, that's what I meant. Only the updated values will be different in corresponding rows in those two virtual tables. So it might be challenging to determine the corresponding rows in the `DELETED` table. If certain key values remain untouched, it will be easy, but if key values are updated, it could become ugly, I guess.

Comment: Your trigger is triggered by a specific UPDATE query. Is the `WORK_ORDER.rowid` field affected by your update query as well? In that case, you cannot use that field in your join, of course; and then you need to join the rows in the `DELETED` table based on other matches/criteria.

Comment: The rowid value will never change, no.

Comment: I just created a small test script to check such a trigger's behavior. I have no issues whatsoever using a join with both the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables within the trigger. So I cannot reproduce your issue. Can you please provide a small script yourself that creates a table and a trigger which demonstrate your issue at hand, so that it can be investigated in some more detail? And can you please also specify which version of SQL Server you are using here (just for the sake of completeness)?

Answer (score 0):

You defined your trigger as "AFTER UPDATE", which means by the time your trigger has processed the DELETED rows are no longer *in* WORK_ORDER at all!

Well, some might be, if a row is counted as UPDATED then it's in both the DELETED and INSERTED table with the same ID, so you might get some, but you won't get all.

To solve this, reference the data exclusively through DELETED because all fields are there, or, if you need new values, you could do a UNION ALL split by in DELETED and NOT IN INSERTED vs. in DELETED and IN INSERTED.

And BTW, you can select specific fields from DELETED, you don't need to select the whole row.

Comment: "You defined your trigger as "AFTER UPDATE", which means by the time your trigger has processed the DELETED rows are no longer in WORK_ORDER at all!" . . . I thought so as well at first, but when you execute an UPDATE query, nothing gets actually deleted... The `DELETED` table will contain the old state and the `INSERTED` table will contain the new state.

Comment: So in general I would agree, but I guess that the relation between the rows in the `INSERTED` and the `DELETED` tables can be complex if key values are updated or if the target table is allowed to hold duplicate rows.

Comment: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ccdeea1902456fe1ed791e845d88f9a6) to demonstrate that both `inserted` and `deleted` have data in them in an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger.

Comment: What do you mean by reference the date exclusively? What if that is the value changing (which in most cases it is)?

Comment: @Nick it was a typo, thanks for catching! If a value changed as opposed to deleting the row, the row is in both INSERTED and DELETED and you can compare old and new values. If you use a primary key, the user can't change it and you can link INSERTED and DELETED on it.